# Dipole antenna radiation field equation

Tags: antenna, dipole, radiation-pattern

Can anybody provide me with an idealised formula that describes the radiation pattern of an omnidirectional dipole antenna?

In particular I am interested in the formula that creates a plot similar to the following:

[image]

Note: I am looking for a simplified closed-form equation, not a full field simulation.

Comment: The polar pattern in the OP reports 10.46 dBi "gain," which is much higher than the 2.15 dBi directivity of a center-fed, 1/2-wave dipole in free space.

Answer (score 7):

The antenna you describe is "omnidirectional" only in the *xy*-plane; it has zero radiation along the *z*-axis. Thus, your dipole is mounted vertically; i.e., *x*=0 and *y*=0 for all segments.

According to *Antennas* by John Kraus, the far *E*-field for a center-fed $\lambda/2$ dipole in free space is:

$$E = \frac{\cos\left({\pi\over 2}\cos\theta\right)}{\sin\theta}$$

In the case of a vertically mounted antenna, $\theta$=0 at the horizon of the plot.

Comment: You might add that power, as plotted by EZNEC, is proportional to the square of the E-field.

Comment: If the OP really is interested in the equation to calculate the polar pattern included there — that would _not_ be the Kraus equation shown in the answer, to date.

Comment: Dick, please enlighten us with the correct equation.

Comment: That would require an accurate definition of the radiator/array to which that pattern applies, which was not provided.